# How can I make iptables rules persist permanently between reboots on this embedded Linux system?

Tags: linux-networking

I am making changes to iptables firewall rules, and I want them to stick permanently, but they disappear everytime the computer reboots. Before you even think of responding, please read the following thoroughly :

- This system has no internet connection.
- I cannot use nor can I install packages `iptables-persistent` nor `iptables-services`
- There is no `systemctl`
- No `service`
- No `sysv-rc-conf`

This system is running crontab and rc.d   I have attempted all the following and none of them work . The iptables rules are still wiped at boot.

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/rules.v4
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

Editing /etc/rc.local with the following contents,

```
#!/bin/sh -e
 #
 sleep 3
 iptables-restore /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
 exit 0
```

When I land on a shell after boot, I can perform,

`$ iptables-restore /etc/iptables/iptables.rules`

and it works as expected. But it is like rc.local is not even executing at boot.   Using rc.local is not necessary, and any solution to the original problem is welcome. I was merely enumerating all the things I have tried already that do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your /etc/rc.local executable? Assuming it is, does `sudo /etc/rc.local` yield anything?

Is iptables-restore on the $PATH when rc.local runs? Do you need to use the full path to iptables-restore, presumably something like `/usr/sbin/iptables-restore`?

Comment: I simply added a script to /etc/network/if-up.d/  to perform the restore. That works for my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a script to /etc/network/if-up.d/ to perform the restore. That works for my machine.